# Creating view from multiple databases linked by columns with db name

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Hi I need to create a view or stored procedure that combines data and returns a result set from 3 different databases on the same server using a column that holds a schema (db) name.

For Example on the first DB I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CloudUsers](
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Username nvarchar(50) NULL,
    MainDB nvarchar(100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Each CloudUser has a separate DB so next now I need to fetch the data from the User database using the MainDB name. The data I need is always 1 row cause I'm using aggregate functions / query.

So in the User MainDB let's say I have this table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CLIENT](
   ID int NOT NULL,
   Name nvarchar(50) NULL,
   ProjectDBName [nvarchar](100) NULL
   CreationDate datetime NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I query like:

```
select min(CreationDate) from MainDB.Client
```

The same Idea for the Client I need to fetch even more data from a 3rd database that points to the Client ProjectDBName. Again it's aggregate data:

```
select Count(id) as TotalTransactions from ProjectDBName.Journal
```

My final result should have records from all databases. It's readonly data that I need for statistics.

Final result set example:

CloudUsers.Username, MainDB->CreationDate, ProjectDBName->TotalTransaction

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: So what is the problem? It looks like you already have all the SQL...

Comment: The problem is that MainDB is a string and I need for each record in CloudUser to fetch data from MainDB but I don't even know how to do it? Should I be using Cursors should I be using another method of dynamically executing SQL which parses MainDB for each record in my CloudUsers Table ? even if I have done that how do I make it as a 1 result set without joins cause I don't really have a join parameter the only link to the other tables is that they come from my specified database column.

Comment: You'll need to do it with dynamic SQL then. If you can do it with a programming language outside the database the code would probably be a lot cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy - and without a schema and sample data, I can't give you a precise answer.

You need to iterate through each client, and use [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx) to execute a the query against the mainDB and projectDB join. You can either do that in one gigantic "union" query, or by creating a temporary table and inserting the data into that temporary table, and then selecting from the temp table at the end of the query.

Comment: Hey Neville, thanks for your comment I'll add sample data. I could have tried to do it with C# code aswell but I think it's more appropriate to do it in the database as I need to connect to many different databases.

Answer (score 0):

For you who are curious of how to solve this issue I have found my own solution using some cursors + dynamic and a simple table variable, enjoy.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CloudAnalysis as
DECLARE @objcursor cursor
DECLARE @innercursor cursor
DECLARE @userid int
       ,@maindb nvarchar(100)
       ,@clientid int
       ,@name nvarchar(50)
       ,@projdb nvarchar(100)
       ,@stat nvarchar(50)
       ,@sql nvarchar(max)
       ,@vsql nvarchar(max)
       ,@rowcount int


DECLARE @result table(userid int,clientid int,maindb nvarchar(100),name nvarchar(50),projdb nvarchar(100),stat nvarchar(50))

SET @objcursor =  CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR SELECT c.id,c.maindb,u.client_id FROM dbo.ClientUsers c join dbo.UserClients u on c.id = u.user_id  open @objcursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @objcursor INTO @userid,@maindb,@clientid
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @maindb 
OR name = @maindb)))
BEGIN

    set @sql = N'SELECT @name = c.name,@projdb=c.ProjectDBName FROM ' + @maindb + '.dbo.CLIENT c WHERE c.id = ' + cast(@clientid as nvarchar)


    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@name NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT,@projdb NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT', 
    @name = @name OUTPUT
    ,@projdb = @projdb OUTPUT

    SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF @rowcount > 0
    BEGIN

    --print '    client: ' + cast(@clientid as nvarchar)+
    --':' + @name + ' projdb: ' + @projdb

    IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @projdb 
    OR name = @projdb)))
    BEGIN

    SET @sql = N'SELECT @stat = j.stat FROM ' + @projdb + '.dbo.JournalTransaction j'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
    ,N'@stat NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT'
    ,@stat = @stat OUTPUT

    END

    INSERT INTO @result (userid,clientid,maindb,name,projdb,stat)
    VALUES (@userid,@clientid,@maindb,@name,@projdb,@stat)

    END

END

FETCH NEXT FROM @objcursor INTO @userid,@maindb,@clientid


END

CLOSE @objcursor
DEALLOCATE @objcursor 

SELECT * FROM @result
```